# Adding third DC to a domain - but the ADDS password is unkown

Tags: active-directory, passwords

I work for an MSP, We have a client that wants us to add a third DC to their production domain. We didn't build the domain. The previous admin gave us three or four different passwords to try.

When I did this, I put the password in, the DC joined the domain as a computer, but was not listed as a DC. Running DCDIAG showed access errors on  some of the tests.

I then powered off one of the existing DCs, and demoted the third DC, removed it from the domain.

Is there anyway to non-destructively test the other passwords to see if they work. I am just afraid that I will screw something up with the adding and subsequent removal of a planned AD.

I find it rather odd that the DCPROMO process completed with an incorrect password. One would think that that would be tested before anything else was done.

Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
S

Answer (score 0):

Domain Admin rights should be fine for promoting the server.

Leave the two DCs online.
Domain join the new server.
Run [Install-ADDSDomainController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsdeployment/install-addsdomaincontroller?view=windowsserver2022-ps).

Comment: worked with a coworker, the password that is was requesting, was the password was for the restore of the DC. The reason that I was getting errors was because the DNS servers order was a little off. The DNS settings were DC1, DC2, and this guy. Changes it to DC1, This guy, DC2. All the errors went away and repadmin / replsummary, and /syncall complete without errors.